# Can Upsetting Shield style affect a gauntlet with Shielded Gauntlet Style?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Assume we have a character who can assume multiple styles at one time (like a Master of Many Styles Monk). Said character has the full line of [Shielded Gauntlet Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shield-gauntlet-style-combat-style), and also [Upsetting Shield Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/upsetting-shield-style-combat-style). Since Shielded Gauntlet Style says:

> While receiving this shield bonus to AC, your gauntlet or spiked gauntlet is treated as a buckler for the purpose of using other feats and abilities

While Upsetting Shield Style says:

> You can shield bash with a buckler as if it were a light shield ... While using this style, whenever you successfully deal damage to an opponent with a shield bash using your buckler, that opponent takes a –2 penalty on all attack rolls made against you until the start of your next turn.

So we can count our gauntlet as a buckler, and we can bash with a buckler for Upsetting Shield's attack penalty.

Would our Monk hitting people with his gauntlet apply the penalty to them? Would he possibly have to count the attack as though it were a shield bash with a light shield instead of using the scaling dice [Shielded Gauntlet Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shielded-gauntlet-attack-combat) gives?

Comment: This is thematically cool, but damage-wise, seems very subpar for a monk and rend Flurry useless.

Comment: @Zangief the monk would likely only be a dip, since we'd be wearing a 'shield' and thus be ineligible for most monk bonuses anyways. But it does open us up for Shield Slam as well as some neat tricks with shield focus and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options when attacking with all three feats:

- Attack with your gauntlet and cause your gauntlet damage, but the damage is modified by [Shielded Gauntlet Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/upsetting-shield-style-combat-style).
- Shield Bash with your gauntlet and cause the effects and damage of shield bash as if you had used a light shield, including the penalty from [Upsetting Shield Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/upsetting-shield-style-combat-style), and the damage is also modified by [Shielded Gauntlet Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/upsetting-shield-style-combat-style).
- You can use your new attack of opportunity option to use the disarm or steal maneuvers instead of a regular attack, but neither will cause any damage.