# Shielded gauntlet style and monk abilities

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94152/can-upsetting-shield-style-affect-a-gauntlet-with-shielded-gauntlet-style) got me thinking:

> While receiving this shield bonus to AC, your gauntlet or spiked gauntlet is **treated as a buckler** for the purpose of using other feats and abilities

Does this mean that a monk loses his AC bonus and flurry when using shielded gauntlet style as it makes the gauntlet be treated as buckler (shield) for the purpose of using other feats and **abilities**?

> When wearing armor, **using a shield**, or carrying a medium or heavy load, a monk loses his AC bonus, as well as his fast movement and flurry of blows abilities.

Bolding mine

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Step by step:

1. You are wearing a gauntlet
2. You are receiving its bonus to AC
3. Thus, for purposes of other abilities, this gauntlet is a buckler (shield)
4. Are you using a shield? Yes, because you are using something that is supposed to be treated as shield.

Rules like this works both ways. You get bonuses from shield feats, but also penalties that goes with shields.